# Disable text selection and edit for ComboBox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

How to prevent any editing and selection attempts for `ComboBox` with `ComboBoxStyle.DropDown` (not `DropDownList`!) setting?
I override `OnKeyDown` and cut any keyboard input but mouse selection events still works and caret is visible.

Comment: ComboBox controls contain a Edit control (where the editing takes place). You don't have direct access to this control. You can however send a `EM_SETREADONLY = 0x00CF` message, to make it ReadOnly. This has the disadvantage of changing the back color of the edit control to gray. Btw, you didn't specify a language.

Comment: I tried to send this message at OnKeyDown (PostMessage(new HandleRef(this, Handle), 0x00CF, (IntPtr)1, IntPtr.Zero);) and nothing changed. Also i need white background, not gray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can propose you two (simple) methods to set a ComboBox text read-only-like.

**Using SendMessage**:
In this case, the `ComboBox` underlying `Edit` Control is set to ReadOnly and - as already said - its background color is painted with the non-active/disabled color (LTGRAY_BRUSH).
The same as if you set a `TextBox` control `ReadOnly` property to true.

```
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
internal static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string lpszClass, string lpszWindow);

[DllImport("User32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint uMsg, int wParam, int lParam);

private const uint EM_SETREADONLY = 0x00CF;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IntPtr EditHandle = FindWindowEx(comboBox1.Handle, IntPtr.Zero, "Edit", null);
    SendMessage(EditHandle, EM_SETREADONLY, 1, 0);
}
```

**Discarding any key press using the Control `KeyDown` event**:
In this case, the `ComboBox` background color of course does not change, but there might be undesired behaviours, depending on its use.

```
private void comboBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
}
```

**Update**:

A method to hide the caret (without subclassing or inheriting):
Here I'm using `FindWindowEx` again. You can assign the `IntPtr EditHandle` to a class scope variable and get the Edit control handle once in the `Form` Load event.

```
[DllImport("user32")]
internal static extern bool HideCaret(IntPtr hWnd);

[DllImport("user32")]
internal static extern bool ShowCaret(IntPtr hWnd);

private void comboBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    comboBox1.Select(0, 0);
    IntPtr EditHandle = FindWindowEx(comboBox1.Handle, IntPtr.Zero, "Edit", null);
    HideCaret(EditHandle);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But blinking cursor still visible, can we also get rid of caret ?

Comment: @Igor Strelkov  See the Update. But, given your requirements, it really looks like you need a DropDownList.

Comment: @IgorStrelkov Just use `EnableWindow(EditHandle, False)`.  If you want to keep the color unchanged, you'll need to respond to `WM_CTLCOLOR*` messages with the proper brush and/or using `SetBkColor()`.